# Redirect issue in production (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have developed a CMS using casein plugin. When I run locally (localhost:3000), everything works fine (login, logout, navigation, etc.). When I push to my main site, and try to login, I get this error:

The webpage at http://.com/admin has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

I have tried clearing my cache/cookies and no luck. I even tried deploying to dev..com and same issue resides. The weird thing is, if I run script/server on .com or dev..com and go to .com:3000 or dev..com:3000, it works fine and the redirect issue does not exists... Before I post any code, has anyone ever seen this before? For some reason my before_filter is not picking up the session when not running script/server.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind... I figured it out... looks like the before_filter was using a controller from the plugin. Weird. Thanks for letting me vent once again stackoverflow! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One case that might cause this:

1. Your authentication mechanism redirects unauthenticated users to root_path
2. root_path tries to authenticate a user and redirects to the sign in page